# Multiple Button with forEach while also accesing onClick handle ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a button which has the properties of **label** and **onClick**. I also have an array with the value I need to pass to the label properties. Here's the code :

```
render(){
{tabel_soal.forEach(function (item, index) {
                <RaisedButton
                    label={item}
                    onClick={this.handleTabelSoalClick}
                    primary={true}
                />
            })}
}
```

With the array in following structure :

```
tabel_soal ={"buttonName1","buttonName2","buttonName3"}
```

But I also need to access the **onClick** properties to run following function :

```
handleTabelSoalClick = () =>{
    const {push} = this.props
    push(`/tabelsampel/getDetailTabel/`+this.state.tabel_soal)
}
```

But currently it showed error that this is not defined.

Is there somewhere I did wrong? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is `push` ? Is it state's property or props or some random variable ? Doing this.props or this.state makes sense but why `this.` ?

Comment: My fault, it supposed to be this.props, i edited it

Comment: tabel_soal needs to be an array and not an object

Comment: @HilalArsa please check my answer and let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you declared the wrong object.

**tabel_soal ={"buttonName1","buttonName2","buttonName3"}**

It should be like this

```
 tabel_soal = {
     "buttonName1": { name: "buttonName1", id: 1 },
     "buttonName2": { name: "buttonName2", id: 2 },
     "buttonName3": { name: "buttonName3", id: 3 }
 }
```

**or**

```
 tabel_soal = {
     "buttonName1": "buttonName1",
     "buttonName2": "buttonName2",
     "buttonName3": "buttonName3"
 }
```

**or**

declared as an array if you want the only key.

```
tabel_soal = ["buttonName1","buttonName2","buttonName3"]
```

> **If you use the first object type then you can do something like this.**

```
render(){
{tabel_soal.forEach(function (item, index) {
                <RaisedButton
                    label={item}
                    onClick={(e)=>this.handleTabelSoalClick(item)}
                    primary={true}
                />
            })}
}
```

And in click event handler you can use the value like this.

```
handleTabelSoalClick = (item) =>{
   .....(`/tabelsampel/getDetailTabel/`+ item.name)
   or
   .....(`/tabelsampel/getDetailTabel/`+ item.id)

}
```

> **If you use the second object type then you can do something like this.**

```
render(){
{tabel_soal.forEach(function (name, index) {
                <RaisedButton
                    label={name}
                    onClick={()=>this.handleTabelSoalClick(name)}
                    primary={true}
                />
            })}
}
```

And in click event handler you can use the value like this.

```
handleTabelSoalClick = (name) =>{
   .....(`/tabelsampel/getDetailTabel/`+ name)    
}
```

> **If you use the third array type then you can do something like this.**

```
render(){
{tabel_soal.forEach(function (name, index) {
                <RaisedButton
                    label={name}
                    onClick={()=>this.handleTabelSoalClick(name,index)}
                    primary={true}
                />
            })}
}
```

And in click event handler you can use the value like this.

```
handleTabelSoalClick = (name,index) =>{
   .....(`/tabelsampel/getDetailTabel/`+ name)   
  or 
   .....(`/tabelsampel/getDetailTabel/`+ tabel_soal[index]) 

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I edited my object and use the third one, and able to access it on the handle.

Answer (score 0):

To get a button do the following and its onclick or the label you can pass the array

```
<RaisedButton
label={tabel_soal}
onClick={()=>this.handleTabelSoalClick(tabel_soal)}
primary={true}
 />
```

and the function will receive the array in param,

```
handleTabelSoalClick = (tabel_soal) =>{
    ...//what ever you need to do with the array.
}
```

---

If you wanna get multiple buttons instead, you can use the following code,

```
render(){
{tabel_soal.map((item, index) =><RaisedButton
                    label={item}
                    onClick={this.handleTabelSoalClick}
                    primary={true}
                />
       )}
}
```